# Dynamically Getting Wordpress Post(image,title) Into my own design(home page latest news section)

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

Hello Everyone i am new in wordpress i want to design a latest news section for my website and want that my post title and image in the post page of wordpress will show in the section i have designed.I have used a blog news function given by the theme but it have its own design.How it is possible that the blog post in the posts can be linked to my design image,title of the post into my design and it will update as the user write new post.I have searched in many places but i can't able to find the solution Thanks [This the screen short of the design i have made and i want that my post title and image will show in it and updated when i create a new post.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJdT3.jpg)

Comment: you can create child theme and edit your template as per your requirement. you can add latest news section in your child theme template.

Comment: Please add the relevant code you have so far to the question.